# Field theory- Irreducible polynomial- Field extensions

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Let $F$ be a field and $p(x)$ be a monic irreducible polynomial over $F$. Suppose $a$ is a root of $p(x)$ in some extension $K$ of $F$. Then $F(a)$ is isomorphic to $F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$

Can someone please explain the proof

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Looks like you may benefit from [reading this](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Re: your question. Have you covered the first isomorphism theorem in the case of rings? If $f:R\to S$ is a homomorphism of rings, then the image is isomorphic to the range moded out by the kernel?

Comment: Yes but how will be the map defined?

Comment: You say "the proof". Which proof? Proof from some textbook? Or you want us to give any proof? If it's the former, please write it down, and if it's the latter, why don't you consult an algebra textbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, notice that $F[x]/(p)$ is a field, because $(p)$ is a maximal ideal in $F[x]$ (since $p$ is irreducible).

Well, consider the evaluation map $ev: F[x] \to F(\alpha)$ by evaluating a polynomial at $\alpha$. This map is a ring homomorphism.

To show the kernel is $(p)$: You need to prove that if any other polynomial $g$ vanishes at $\alpha$, then $p$ must divide $g$.

Let $I \subset k[x]$ be the collection of polynomials $g$ which satisfy $g(\alpha) = 0$. Given $f,g \in I$, $f+g \in I$ because $(f+g)(\alpha) = f(\alpha) + g(\alpha) = 0 + 0 = 0$. Likewise, if $f \in I$ and $g \in k[x]$, then $f \dot g \in I$ because $f \dot g (\alpha) = f(\alpha) g(\alpha) = 0 \dot g(A) = 0$. Hence, $I \subset k[x]$ is an ideal.

Since $k[x]$ is a PID, there exists a $p \in k[x]$ such that $I = (p)$. Thus, $p$ divides $g$ for every $g \in I$. But, the $p$ which I have found and the $p$ which you have written must be the same upto scaling by units since $p$ is irreducible! monicity guarantees a unique choice (so removes the ``upto scaling part'')

The evaluation map is clearly surjective.

Thus, the evaluation map is an isomorphism.